# TFS Build Workflow - InvokeProcess for SC.EXE? Or Custom Activity?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, build-automation

I need to run a command as part of my build workflow.  Specifically, it is sc.exe with certain parameters like this:

```
sc.exe \\computerName STOP "serviceName"
```

In the build workflow, can I just use InvokeProcess activity to do this?  I want to avoid batch files.  Should I use InvokeProcess, and if so, do i have to provide the path to SC.exe.  I would not think so because it's path is recognized no matter the working directory (i think because its a windows system executable).

Or should I do this another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the `InvokeProcess` activity. Set the `FileName` property to "sc.exe" and `Arguments` to

```
String.Format("\\{0} STOP ""{1}""", ComputerName, ServiceName)
```

Assuming there are variables named ComputerName and ServiceName in scope.

Comment: this worked, but do you or anyone know how to make the command wait until the service is actually stopped. I don't want to go to the next step in my build workflow until i know that the service is stopped.

Comment: If you want to stop a service and wait for it to stop, you could create a `While` loop that runs `sc query` and loops in a Delay until the query says stopped.

Comment: A little late but inside a Whle activity call a batch from InvokeProcess that does a 'sc.exe %1 query %2 | find /C /I "%3"' where %1 is the server name (with slashes), %2 is the ServiceKeyName you are looking for (so if it was the world wide publishing service plug in W3SVC) and finally %3 is the unique verbiage you are looking for (like STOPPED or RUNNING, in quotes). It will return 1 if the work id found and 0 if not. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the FileName property to "cmd.exe" and then set Arguments to 
"/c sc.exe \\computerName STOP " + ServiceName